# Meu index está dando um retorno de Undefined variable: imagem

Tags: laravel

Criei meu index assim só que está me retornando um erro na view para eu conseguir obter a imagem : Undefined variable: imagem (View: /var/www/html/fernandosite/resources/views/admin/marcadaguas/index.blade.php)

```html
      @foreach($imagem as $image)
          <tr>
            <td class="text-my-color-4">
              {{ $image->id }}
            </td>
            <td class="text-my-color-4">
              <img src="{{$image->imagem}}" class="rounded img-fluid" style="height: 50px;">
            </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
```

e no meu controller está assim o index:

```html
public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.marcadaguas.index')->with('imagem', Marcadagua::all());
    }
```

No meu store está assim:

```html
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        $this->validate($request,[
            'imagem' => 'required|image',
            'perfil' => 'required|image',
            'logomarca' => 'required|image',
            'nome' => 'required',
        ]);

        $imagem = $request->file('imagem');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $imagem->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $perfil = $request->file('perfil');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $perfil->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $logomarca = $request->file('logomarca');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $logomarca->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $nome = $request->nome;
       
        $imagem = Image::make($imagem)->fit(1080,720);
        $perfil = Image::make($perfil)->fit(140,140);
        $logomarca = Image::make($logomarca)->fit(140,140);
        
        Image::make($imagem)->insert($perfil, 'top-left', 0,15)->insert($logomarca, 'bottom-left', 0,5)->insert(public_path('marcadagua/principal.png'), 'bottom-left', 0, 0)
        ->text($nome, 70, 170, function($font) {
            $font->file('marcadagua/RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf');
            $font->size(15);
            $font->color('#2BB7C4');
            $font->align('center');
            $font->valign('top');
        })->save('uploads/posts/' . $filename );

       $imagem = Marcadagua::create([ 
        'imagem' => 'uploads/posts/' . $filename,

        ]);

        Session::flash('success', 'Post criado com sucesso.');
        
        return view('admin.marcadaguas.index');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua função **store** não está enviando nenhuma variável chamada **imagem** para sua view.
Tente retornar a rota para seu **controller** acessando a função **index** no final da sua função **store**, algo parecido com:

```
    public function store(Request $request){
       ...
       return route(rota.para.index.controller);
    }
```